# What are the limits to getting aws confirmation codes?

Tags: android, ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Hi guys so I made an app where users register through AWS cognito. I gave the app to 20 friends and they were able to successfully get confirmation codes and register, however the next 20 friends I gave the app to were not  able to receive a confirmation code, and I cannot for the love of god figure out why both our IOS and android app cannot receive confirmation codes anymore.

Does anyone know what to do? There's is nothing in the docs about confirmation code limits and I don't know where to go to up the limit if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito will try to send your confirmation codes all the time. To do this, relies on AmazonSNS to send the SMS. Now your account comes with a certain quota for the SNS service. If you have gone past this limit your messages will not be sent. Unfortunately, Cognito currently has no way to know if you are passed this limit or not.

https://aws.amazon.com/sns/pricing/

docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_preferences.html

Comment: what's the wait time for the quota to reset?

Comment: Free tier is 100/month

Comment: @TheQ there are budget limits that you control and a spending limit that you need to ask AWS Support to increase for you: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_preferences.html.